# Strange versions conflict in sbt strict mode

Tags: sbt, coursier

Why sbt (1.3.5) fail to resolve identical dependencies in strict mode?

```
> cat build.sbt
conflictManager := sbt.ConflictManager.strict
libraryDependencies += "io.grpc" % "grpc-all" % "1.26.0"
```

```
sbt:test> compile
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last update for the full output
[error] (update) lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.error.conflict.StrictRule: Rule Strict(Set(ModuleMatcher(*:*)),Set(),false,true,false) not satisfied: lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.params.rule.Strict$EvictedDependencies: Unsatisfied rule Strict(*:*): Found evicted dependencies:
[error] 
[error] io.grpc:grpc-api:1.26.0 ([1.26.0] wanted)
[error] └─ io.grpc:grpc-all:1.26.0
[error] 
[error] io.grpc:grpc-api:1.26.0 ([1.26.0] wanted)
[error] └─ io.grpc:grpc-auth:1.26.0
[error]    └─ io.grpc:grpc-all:1.26.0
[error] 
[error] io.grpc:grpc-api:1.26.0 ([1.26.0] wanted)
[error] └─ io.grpc:grpc-core:1.26.0
[error]    ├─ io.grpc:grpc-all:1.26.0
[error]    ├─ io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.26.0
[error]    │  └─ io.grpc:grpc-all:1.26.0
[error]    ├─ io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.26.0
[error]    │  └─ io.grpc:grpc-all:1.26.0
[error]    └─ io.grpc:grpc-testing:1.26.0
[error]       └─ io.grpc:grpc-all:1.26.0
[error] 
[error] io.netty:netty-codec-http2:4.1.42.Final ([4.1.42.Final] wanted)
[error] └─ io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.26.0
[error]    └─ io.grpc:grpc-all:1.26.0
[error] 
[error] io.grpc:grpc-core:1.26.0 ([1.26.0] wanted)
[error] └─ io.grpc:grpc-all:1.26.0
[error] 
[error] io.grpc:grpc-core:1.26.0 ([1.26.0] wanted)
[error] └─ io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.26.0
[error]    └─ io.grpc:grpc-all:1.26.0
[error] 
[error] io.grpc:grpc-core:1.26.0 ([1.26.0] wanted)
[error] └─ io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.26.0
[error]    └─ io.grpc:grpc-all:1.26.0
[error] 
[error] io.grpc:grpc-core:1.26.0 ([1.26.0] wanted)
[error] └─ io.grpc:grpc-testing:1.26.0
[error]    └─ io.grpc:grpc-all:1.26.0
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 19.12.2019 13:38:43
```

Expected and actual versions are the same. However, explicit version override works, but it's annoying to resolve all transitive dependencies.

Is it sbt or coursier bug?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it sbt or coursier bug?

I am not 100% sure, but I'd think this is something that would require a fix in Coursier.

An interesting thing about grpc that might not be obvious at the first glance is that it is declaring its dependencies using version range `[1.26.0]` as opposed to just saying `1.26.0`. This can be confirmed by looking at their [POM file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-all/1.26.0/grpc-all-1.26.0.pom).

Coursier (or shaded lm-coursier with `relaxedForAllModules` set as Reconciliation strategy to be specific) seems to be resolving for example `grpc-api` correctly to `1.26.0`, but take a look at `show updateFull`:

```
...
[info]  io.grpc:grpc-api
[info]      - 1.26.0
[info]          evicted: false
[info]          homepage: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java
[info]          configurations: test, optional, compile, default, runtime
[info]          callers: io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.26.0, io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.26.0, io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.26.0, io.grpc:grpc-all:1.26.0, io.grpc:grpc-core:1.26.0, io.grpc:grpc-auth:1.26.0
[info]      - [1.26.0]
[info]          evicted: true
[info]          evictedData: version selection
[info]          homepage: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java
[info]          configurations: test, optional, compile, default, runtime
[info]          callers: io.grpc:grpc-all:1.26.0
[info]      - [1.26.0]
[info]          evicted: true
[info]          evictedData: version selection
[info]          homepage: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java
[info]          configurations: test, optional, compile, default, runtime
[info]          callers: io.grpc:grpc-auth:1.26.0
[info]      - [1.26.0]
[info]          evicted: true
[info]          evictedData: version selection
[info]          homepage: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java
[info]          configurations: test, optional, compile, default, runtime
[info]          callers: io.grpc:grpc-core:1.26.0
...
```

It is incorrectly reporting `[1.26.0]` as a version that was evicted by `1.26.0`. It's also including the same stuff three times with different caller.

Since sbt generates eviction report based on the update report, if this is fixed, I think the eviction report would be fixed on its own.